# Java - Dropdown Component Display

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dropdown, cascadingdropdown

I want to be able to create a Java GUI that works similar to the "Design" tab you can view when opening an XML file in Eclipse.

Essentially, I want to be able to have (the visual equivalent of) a click-able component with a title, which opens up to display a JPanel if you click it (and hides the panel again if you click again).

Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcI0O.jpg

Does anyone know if Java has any class that can be used like that?

Comment: You can use [JTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).

Comment: Can that allow me to add a TextField to edit a "field" of information? Alternatively, can I make it so that if I click a "leaf" it opens a second window where I CAN put such an input component?

Comment: @AnjuMaaka in the 4 minutes from the time you received the suggestion until you replied did you read the entire tutorial?

Comment: No, I read enough to see that it COULD be the solution I wanted. Then I asked the question before I started reading up on the details, for two reasons. First; a person with experience will always be better at understanding a question than you will from just reading documentation. Second; given the answer times I wanted to, possibly, have a reply by the time I finished reading the documentation

Comment: @AnjuMaaka yes, you can do it. You can also edit values directly in your tree.